# Executar programa no linux de uma maneira mais fácil (gerado pelo electron)

Tags: linux, electron

fiz o build com esse comando

ng build --prod && electron-packager . gitrun --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/logo.png

Para execultar o aquivo tenho que entrar na pasta do projeto abrir o terminal e rodar ./gitrun

tem alguma maneira de facilitar isso para passar o programa para usuarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme a documentação: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution

Primeiro deve baixar os binários pré-compilados: https://github.com/electron/electron/releases

Depois copiar a pasta do teu projeto para dentro da pasta `./resources` dos pré-compilados

A estrutura em MacOSX deve estar:

```
electron/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/
├── package.json
├── main.js
└── index.html
```

E Windows ou Linux assim:

```
electron/resources/app
├── package.json
├── main.js
└── index.html
```

A pasta `./app` é o teu projeto no caso, depois notará na pasta acima em Windows o `electron.exe` no linux será apenas `electron` sem extensão, mas é um executável, ambos podem ser renomeados para o nome do teu programa ou como desejar.

No Mac a propria pasta `Electron.app` é um aplicativo (é assim que funciona no Mac).

Você também pode compactar em ASAR conforme dito em: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution#distribuindo-seu-app-como-apenas-um-arquivo

Para empacotar instale globalmente o asar:

```
npm install -g asar
```

E depois aponte a pasta do teu projeto no comando trocando `<pasta do projeto>` pela sua pasta:

```
asar pack <pasta do projeto> app.asar
```

Em linux e windows deve colocar dentro do pré-compilado assim:

```
electron/resources/
└── app.asar
```

E o processo é o mesmo, em linux execute o arquivo `electron` no windows execute o `electron.exe` (mais uma vez ambos podem ser renomeados)

Em Mac deve ser este o caminho:

```
electron/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/
└── app.asar
```

---

Para facilitar existe o https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager

> **Nota:** Não testei, talvez no fim de semana eu teste com calma e faça uma revisão

Para instalar:

```
npm install electron-packager -g
```

Então execute o comando conforme o ambiente desejado:

```
electron-packager <sourcedir> <appname> --platform=<platform> --arch=<arch>
```

sourcedir é a pasta do projeto, appname é o nome do app desejado, platform a plataforma de destino, no caso platform e arch podem ser omitidos se for usar o parametro `--all` que irá gerar para todas plataformas disponíveis

Você também pode instalar o electron-packager como devDependencies diretamente no teu projeto e adicionar no package.json no build, algo semelhante a isto

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "electron-packager ."
  },
```

> A resposta esta em edição/melhorias

---

### Controvérsias e opinião pessoal

Um grande problema que muitos devs sofrem é a engenharia reversa, ainda mais quando os apps tem dados sensíveis, tipo chaves privadas para autenticação, o Electron não é nem de longe um ambiente seguro visto deste ponto de vista, sabendo bem o que faz, isolando uma chave por pessoa evitando de criar uma comunicação com seu back-end de forma exposta o Electron não vai ser um problema, mas se não tiver conhecimento de segurança razoável qualquer pessoa com algum conhecimento vai poder extrair o `asar` (um baita aZar/aSar, desculpem a piada) e analisar o código para ver como explorar brechas.

Quase todos "EXEs da vida" podem sofrer com isto, **mas o formato `asar` é imensamente mais fácil de sofrer com isto**.

Existe soluções que considero paliativas ou chame como pequenos reforços como o pacote: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js (não cheguei a testar), talvez o Electron já possua algo próprio, faz algum tempo que não trabalho com ele (mudei para outra plataforma), mas mesmo isto não é solução é apenas um reforço. Então deve sempre pensar nestes detalhes.

O texto até o momento não é para sugerir soluções mirabolantes, mágicas ou qualquer coisa assim, porque engenharia reversa não é algo que tem solução, o que podemos fazer é dificultar ou criar um ambiente (como chaves) para cada pessoa, fazendo assim o único responsável ser o próprio usuário, mas não vou entrar em detalhes porque isto pode confundir muita gente e realmente precisarei revisar o texto no texto no futuro.

> Em edição para o futuro, irei sugerir ferramenta(s) que fazem um pack completo em um arquivo único executável que pode ajudar, mas não é infalível contra engenharia reversa